# GDPR dilemma: Does a full name contained in a URL constitute PII as stated by Google Analytics?

Tags: gdpr

But wait, it gets better: This full name belongs to person who was interviewed in an article under this URL.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7686480?hl=en

> What Google considers PII: ... full names or usernames

Now, probably the right question would be: Should common CMS's such as Wordpress censor names from URLs?

PS: This is a rather food for thought question, I do not expect you to provide a correct answer, I am more interested in your point of view on this specific use case.

Comment: Are you trying to say any harm here is WordPress's fault? I don't think it is responsible for how you configure it.

Comment: No, you have misread what I am asking. That's just additional food for thought.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing your terms; [GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-4-gdpr/) talks about personal data:

> ‘Personal data’ means any information relating to an identified or
>   identifiable natural person (‘data subject’); an identifiable natural
>   person is one who can be identified, directly or indirectly, in
>   particular by reference to an identifier such as a name, an
>   identification number, location data, an online identifier or to one
>   or more factors specific to the physical, physiological, genetic,
>   mental, economic, cultural or social identity of that natural person.

PII is more a US term, for which NIST says:

> PII is any information about an individual maintained by an agency,
>   including (1) any information that can be used to distinguish or trace
>   an individual‘s identity, such as name, social security number, date
>   and place of birth, mother‘s maiden name, or biometric records; and
>   (2) any other information that is linked or linkable to an individual,
>   such as medical, educational, financial, and employment information.

Either way around, a name is clearly personal data. However, that just means it has to be processed appropriately. You can't sue Twitter because https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump might identify a particular individual.

Comment: I am not mixing anything. Please, read my clearly stated question again. It is against GA's policy to store PII (or personal data) - in this case a full name.

GDPR audits require you to analyze sources where personal data is stored. In this case it is GA (URL/page report).